# Measure Theorem Ellipsoid

Tags: measure-theory

I want to find the measure of ellipsoid S:
$$S= (x,y,z)\in R: \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}<1 $$
I know $\int_{S} 1 = \mu(S)$. I think it's smart to use spherical/ellipsoid coordinates for this, so: $
x = at\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) \\
y = bt\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) \\
z = ct\cos(\theta).$

Then I have to find the Jacobian matrix and determinant of $g(t,\theta,\phi)=(at\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi),bt\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), ct\cos(\theta)) $.

Then I'll find the answer when I do this: $$\int_{S} 1 = \mu(S)= \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} Jacobian\ \ dt\ d\phi\ d\theta  $$

But the Jacobian-determinant is not a nice expression, so I think I do something wrong. Maybe in the parameterization with the $t$??

I hope someone wants to help me, thanks in advance!

Edit:

Jacobi-matrix = \begin{array}{cc}
   sin(\theta)cos(\phi) & a\ t\ cos (\theta)cos(\phi) & -a\ t\ sin(\theta)sin(\phi)\\
   sin(\theta)sin(\phi) & b\ t\ cos(\theta)sin(\phi) & b\ t\ sin(\theta)cos(\phi)\\
c\ cos(\theta) & -c\ t\ sin(\theta) & 0\\
  \end{array}

Determinant: $a\cdot b \cdot c \ t^2\  cos(\theta)cos(\phi)sin(\theta)cos(\phi)cos(\theta) \\
a\cdot c\ t^2\ sin(\theta)sin(\phi) sin(\theta)sin(\phi) sin(\theta)+ \\
b\cdot c\ t^2\ sin(\theta)cos(\phi) sin(\theta)cos(\phi)sin(\theta) +\\
a\cdot b \cdot c\ t^2\ sin(\theta)sin(\phi) cos(\theta)sin(\phi) cos(\theta) $

And that's the same as: 
$$ Jacobian: t^2\ \left( a\cdot b \cdot c \ cos^2(\theta)cos^2(\phi)sin(\theta) 
+ a\cdot c\ sin^3(\theta)sin^2(\phi) + 
b\cdot c\ sin^3(\theta)cos^2(\phi) +
a\cdot b \cdot c\ sin(\theta)sin^2(\phi) cos^2(\theta) \right) $$

Comment: You can do this, or you can transform the ellipsoid to a unit sphere via a linear map.

Comment: A determinant is a determinant, and if you don't make mistakes, it will simplify to a rather nice expression. If you want a check for mistakes, you'll have to post your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Using reduced coordinates makes your life easier:

Let $x=a X$, $y=b Y$ and $z=c Z$

\begin{align*}
  \iiint_{x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2<1} \, dV &=
  abc \iiint_{X^2+Y^2+Z^2<1} \, dX \, dY \, dZ \\
  &=
  abc\int_{-1}^{1}
  \left[
    \int_{-\sqrt{1-X^2}}^{\sqrt{1-X^2}}
    \left( \int_{-\sqrt{1-X^2-Y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-X^2-Y^2}} dZ \right) dY
  \right] dX \\
  &= 
  abc\int_{-1}^{1}
  \left[
    \int_{-\sqrt{1-X^2}}^{\sqrt{1-X^2}}
    2\sqrt{1-X^2-Y^2} dY
  \right] dX \\
  &= abc\int_{-1}^{1} \pi (1-X^2) \, dX \\
  &= \frac{4\pi abc}{3}
\end{align*}